# Rails authorization plugins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, declarative-authorization

We are evaluating plugins for Authorization in Rails.  The two at the top of our list are 
cancan and declarative_authorization.

I would like to get some feedback from anyone currently using either of these plugins.

The problem we are going to face with any authorization plugin is that we have a 
database per customer model and will need to modify the plugin to work within that 
model.  Because of this fact I'm interested in hearing from anyone who has had to tweak the
plugins at all as well.

I'm just starting to look around at the code.  It seems like cancan might be a little easier to customize.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using declarative_authorization.  Now it seems that auth_logic is where the community is headed.

declarative_auth would have been really simple if it wasn't for our apps multi-tennant db
model.  I had to modify the source a bit to make it all work, but it wasn't too tough to do, and
I was pretty green when I started this project.

It seems like you really can't go wrong with any of the solutions.  cancan seemed cool too
but it would have needed more mods for what I was doing so I decided against it.

Its written by Ryan Bates though which is cool.  Love rails casts!  :)

I know this post is old but I figured I'll update any because you never know.

Comment: auth_logic and declarative_authorization are very different. auth_logic just lets authenticate a user vs. declarative_authorization which gives fine tuned control over what your users have access to in your app.

Comment: I posted this a while ago, but just in case it comes up in future searches I figured I'd update it.  In my latest project I'm using Devise for authentication and Ryan Bates` cancan for authorization.  Both a pretty great!  I'm using rails 3 and have had no issues. This project doesn't have the multiple database per customer model so I didn't have to modify the source for the plugin's at all!

Answer (score 4):

Cancan is a lighter weight plugin for smaller sites.  You can see a video on railscasts.
http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan

I've used declarative_authorization with authlogic/restful_auth for several projects.  It has everything you would need.  1) Model security. 2) Controller security 3) methods available to the view to check auth.

The only frustrating thing I've run into with declarative_authorization is me not reading the rdocs.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/188-declarative-authorization

Answer (score 1):

## Authority

I'd suggest you also check out my new gem, [Authority](https://github.com/nathanl/authority). Because you do the actual logic in plain Ruby classes and methods, you can check any data source you need to: different databases, static files, phases of the moon via a web request, you name it. :)